# Why javafx application fails to start with Platform.runLater and why hangs up with lambda expression?

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, lambda

I have simple javafx HelloWord application, but when i try to start it properly using Platform.runLater i receive java.lang.RuntimeException. Similarly when i try to use lambda expression, my frame doesn't show up. Program prints 'starting', but hangs up on showing the frame.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainFrame extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MainFrame.launch(args);
            }
        });

        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            System.out.println("starting");
            launch(args);
            System.out.println("started");
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setOnAction((e)->System.out.println("Hello World!"));

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

This is entire output produced by the application:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Error: class MainFrame$1 is not a subclass of javafx.application.Application
    at javafx.application.Application.launch(Unknown Source)
    at MainFrame$1.run(MainFrame.java:15)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
starting
```

Could anyone explain to me why i receive exception and why lambda expression hangs up application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Application.launch(args)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html#launch-java.lang.String...-) is equivalent to [`Application.launch(TheClass.class, args)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html#launch-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String...-), where `TheClass` is the *immediately enclosing class* of the method call. `TheClass` must be a subclass of `Application`, else an `IllegalArgumentException` is thrown. The immediately enclosing class in your first code block is the anonymous inner `Runnable` subclass that is not itself a subclass of `Application`, so you get the `IllegalArgumentException`.

Your assumption that the proper way to start a JavaFX application is by calling `launch()` from the FX Application Thread is incorrect. In fact, the FX Application Thread will not be running until the FX toolkit is started, and that will not happen until `launch()` is called. Hence your second code block just doesn't do anything: there is no FX Application Thread on which to execute `launch()`. In addition, the `launch()` method blocks until the application exits (again, see [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html#launch-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String...-)); so even if the FX Application Thread were running(*), you would simply deadlock it as it would be blocked, waiting for its own exit.

The "proper" way to start a JavaFX Application is simply to call `launch()` from the main thread (or any other thread, but not the JavaFX Application Thread):

```
public class MainFrame extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Calling launch from main thread: "+Thread.currentThread());
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        System.out.println("start() invoked on thread: "+Thread.currentThread());
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setOnAction((e)->System.out.println("Hello World!"));

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Calling `launch()` here will start the FX toolkit, start the FX Application Thread and create an instance of `MainFrame`. Then, on the FX Application Thread, it will create a `Stage` and pass it to the `MainFrame` instance's `start()` method.

(*) I think the way you have your code, the first failed attempt to call `launch()` will actually start the FX Toolkit, so the second attempt does call `launch()` on the FX Application Thread, causing deadlock as described.

Comment: I thought that Platform.runLater is javafx equivalent to SwingUtilities.invokeLater where you have to create application on event dispatch thread. Apparently it is not.

Comment: @hal `Platform.runLater()` is exactly the equivalent of `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`, and the threading rules are essentially the same (you can only create *windows* (not "applications") and modify "live" components on the UI thread). But note here that your (badly named) `MainFrame` class is *not* a window subclass or a subclass of a UI component. The `launch()` method essentially implements the call to `Platform.runLater(() -> new MainFrame().start(new Stage()));` for you (though it is doing more complex things than that).